# Extract Month name and year and the sort them to be used as x.axis in R

Tags: r, date, plot, shiny

I have tried a number of methods realise that but in vain . I have data in terms of a date (DD.MM.YY) and am trying to get the following : Name of the Month-YYYY and then sort them to use them as x.axis:

```
ID    Date         Month_Yr
1     02.08.2022   August-2022
2     03.11.2022   November-2022
3     07.06.2021   Jun-2021
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a bit like a XY-problem.

I suggest to do the labelling using ggplot's `scale_x_date()`

```
#sample data
mydata <- data.frame( date = seq(as.Date("2022-01-01", format = "%Y-%m-%d"), 
                                 as.Date("2022-12-31", format = "%Y-%m-%d"), by = 1),
                      value = 1:365)


#plot with data-axis an labels
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = date, y = value)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels =  "%b-%Y") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to have the entire name of the month  + capital first letter.Thank you for the nice  solution

Comment: sure.. use `%B` in stead of `%b`

Comment: the problem is that in my R shiny app the user will have user input containing values in form of name of month-Year and not numericals in form of "2022-01-01" so what will be sorted is a column containing dates in form Month name-year that matches the choice of the user (of course user chosse more than one month and more than a year and if he chosses one date(Month Name-Year) then it plots only one value corrspending to that date).I hope you can understand me

Comment: first of all i want to transform that column containnig the dates "%Y-%m-%d" to Month name-Year and then those will user input values (unique).Every time user chooses multiple choices then the data will filtered based oh those choices .then we plot some other column vs sorted date columns(month name _Year)

Comment: Probably it is better to ask a new question, with all relevant sample data and R-code to reproduce your issue (as short as possible, so cut out all stuff not needed for reproducing the actual problem).

Comment: Thank you very much.For the example you already presented can you please add an y axis that its scale can not be determined using that "trans" formula  .So you have to let  the scale be dynamically determined. This is the biggest in my exampel in r shiny.

Comment: again: if you have a new question, please ask a `new` question :).